# How to merge these two map into one map?

Tags: trigger, map, collection, helper

```
Set<ID> folderIDS =  new Set<ID>();
Map<ID,Custom_Folder__c> foldersToUpdate1 = new Map<ID,Custom_Folder__c>();
Map<ID,Custom_Folder__c> foldersToUpdate2 = new Map<ID,Custom_Folder__c>();

folderIDS.add('a0t63xxxxxxxxxxxx');
folderIDS.add('a0t63xxxxxxxxxxxy');
folderIDS.add('a0t63xxxxxxxxxxxz');

foldersToUpdate1 = getMapFoldersById(folderIDS);
foldersToUpdate2 = getMapFoldersById2(folderIDS);

private static Map<ID,Custom_Folder__c> getMapFoldersById(Set<Id> tmpFolderIDS){
    return new Map<ID,Custom_Folder__c> ([SELECT Id, Student__c From Custom_Folder__c where id in :tmpFolderIDS ]);
}

private static Map<ID,Custom_Folder__c> getMapFoldersById2(Set<Id> tmpFolderIDS){
    return new Map<ID,Custom_Folder__c> ([SELECT Id, Business_Type__c From Custom_Folder__c where id in :tmpFolderIDS ]);
}
```

From the above code I am getting two different map with same object in the trigger helper but there are two methods in 1st method **foldersToUpdate1** is updated and in 2nd method **foldersToUpdate2** is updated. I want to merge two map into one so that I can do only one update if the trigger is invoked.

When I debug it is overwriting the map and the output is removing this field ***Student__c*** in that map

Comment: Why do you even have two separate queries? Just include both fields in one query.

Comment: Basically the set of ids as parameters are different in these two methods. How to handle this situation?

Comment: Your code example contradicts your comments. Please **[edit]** your post to better match your scenario if your connections are actually different.

Comment: I'd say it looks like you are probably running two different operations on those lists because of the queries returning different fields. Do yourself a favor and just have one query that gets both fields, then split/join your records after. This way you wont "lose" fields when merging maps/sets.

Answer (score 1):

Apex [Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm#!) support a union operation, via the `addAll(anotherSet)` method.

Rather than performing two queries, you should combine your Id sets into a single set using this method. You can then perform one SOQL query with an `Id IN :combinedSet` clause. You should include all of the fields you require in your `SELECT` clause.

You can then iterate over your single Map and implement whatever logic and update mechanic you require.